# qTip2 | jQuery "on" method with a different target

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using the very handy [qTip2 library](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).

I have a table which regularly gets replaced when making various ajax requests. I would like a qtip to display at the top of a particular column in the table when the cursor hovers over a `<td>` in that column. To achieve this I've used the `$('body').on(...)` method with the `<th>` as the selector and then setting the selector of "show.target" to be the relevant `<td>` via a class assignment.

I've got it working apart from 2 points:

- The qtip isn't created until I hover over the `<th>` at least once
- Once the qtip displays when I hover over the `<td>`, it won't hide until I hover and leave the `<th>`

Here is the code:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        var tableHtml = '<table><tr><th>Col 1</th><th class="col-2-header">Col 2</th></tr><tr><td>Row Label 1</td><td class="col-2">Val 1</td></tr><tr><td>Row Label 2</td><td class="col-2">Val 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row Label 3</td><td class="col-2">Val 3</td></tr></table>';
        $('body').append(tableHtml);
    }, 100);

    $("body").on("mouseover", '.col-2-header', function (e) {
        $(this).qtip({
            overwrite: false,
            position: {
                my: 'bottom center',
                at: 'top center',
                viewport: $(window)
            },
            content: 'Some test content...',
            show: {
                event: e.type,
                ready: true,
                target: $('td.col-2')
            }
        }, e);
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/6106/

Any pointers welcome.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the jQuery UI tooltip plugin, it has built-in event delegation for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Can't you just replace the body of the table with the ajax calls, not the whole thing?

Comment: @Kevin B Good point but I've inherited this app and it uses qTip2 throughout. I'm only making a small change so don't want to rip and replace for another library just yet. Plus jQuery UI isn't used anywhere else in the app.

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't have control over the result from the ajax call unforunately...

Comment: Event delegation on an event such as mouseover isn't much better than a `setInterval()` with a short delay. I'd just abstract the init into a function and run it within the ajaxcomplete.

Comment: this plugin feels really buggy... even taking out the event delegation it still doesn't show up consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your qTip definition. Instead of running .on for the header, it gets run for anything with the .col-2 class (Gave that class to the header as well) and set a position target for the header column.

[New jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/6107/)

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        var tableHtml = '<table><tr><th>Col 1</th><th class="col-2-header col-2">Col 2</th></tr><tr><td>Row Label 1</td><td class="col-2">Val 1</td></tr><tr><td>Row Label 2</td><td class="col-2">Val 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row Label 3</td><td class="col-2">Val 3</td></tr></table>';
        $('body').append(tableHtml);
    }, 100);

    $("body").on("mouseover", '.col-2', function (e) {
        $(this).qtip({
            overwrite: false,
            position: {
                my: 'bottom center',
                at: 'top center',
                viewport: $(window),
                target: $(".col-2-header")
            },
            content: 'Some test content...',
            show: {
                event: e.type,
                ready: true
            }
        }, e);
    });

});
```

Edit: This seems like a partial fix as the qTip recreates itself when mousing between cells. Might be fixable by playing with the hide: event.

Comment: I think this is better, setting the position.target makes more sense. I'll give this a go, thanks.